# Copy value into NA from one column using criteria from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I´m new using R and I´ve been struggling using tidyverse.

I have created the following data.frame as example. My original data.frame has 180000 obs and 34 vars.

```
name <- c("chem1", "chem2", "chem3", "chem4", "chem5")
cas <- c("29331-92-5", "29331-92-6", NA, "29331-92-4", "29331-92-1" )
tib <- tibble(name, cas)
```

which generate this:

```
tib
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  name  cas       
  <chr> <chr>     
1 chem1 29331-92-5
2 chem2 29331-92-6
3 chem3 NA        
4 chem4 29331-92-4
5 chem5 29331-92-1
```

chem3 and chem1 must have same cas value, however the input file came with a NA value for chem3.
I do not know how to copy into the NA cell the cas value belonging to chem1, that is "29331-92-5".
Although I´ve trying using tidyverse but I am happy receiving any base feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I undestood: the value of chem3 was supposed to be equal to chem1, but your input file came with an error, because in a lot of lines, the values of chem3 are different from chem1.

To correct this, I would make a lookup vector, where the values of each "chem" are the correct values. Whem I make sure that all the values in this lookup vector are correct, I would just past this lookup vector, trough your `tib` data.frame. So to make this, I will first extract all the current unique values of each "chem" as follow:

```
library(tidyverse)
group <- tib %>% 
  group_by(name, cas) %>% 
  summarise(
    count = n()
  )
```

After that, I transform these unique values of `cas`, into a vector, and them, I name each of these values according to their respective `chem`. Since the values of "chem3" are incorrect, I need to equal this value, to the value of "chem1" before I proceed.

```
levels <- group$cas
names(levels) <- group$name
levels["chem3"] <- levels["chem1"]
```

Now that I correct the value of "chem3" in the lookup vector `levels`, I just ask R to repeat these values of `levels`, in the same order as they appear in your `tib` data.frame, and them I save this result in a new column trough the `mutate()` function.

```
tib <- tib %>% 
  mutate(
    correct_cas = levels[tib$name]
  )
```

**Resulting this**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  name  cas        correct_cas
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      
1 chem1 29331-92-5 29331-92-5 
2 chem2 29331-92-6 29331-92-6 
3 chem3 NA         29331-92-5 
4 chem4 29331-92-4 29331-92-4 
5 chem5 29331-92-1 29331-92-1
```

Comment: I tried your code and worked perfectly! However, I´ve got a follow up question (probably very basic). How do you enter an arbitrary number in the NA cell using chem3 row as condition. I mean, I would like to write "7575" in the NA cell.

Comment: Uhmm...that depends on the condition to fill these "gaps", or these NA's values. I mean, do you want to substitute all the NA values? Or is a matter that in all the rows of `chem3`, the values in the `cas` column are NA's, and you want to fill these values with a "7575"?